# i am trying to insert node in bst with while loop but its not working

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-search-tree

this is the function to insert node 
but root is not updating

```
Node *insert(Node **root,int data) {
    Node *k = *root;

    if (*root==NULL) {
        *root = createNode(data);
        return *root;
    }
    else {
        while (*root) {
            // printf("%d", (*root)->data);
            if (data < (*root)->data) {
                *root = (*root)->left;
            } else {
                *root = (*root)->right;
            }
        }

        *root = createNode(data);
        return k;
    }
}
```

this is the function to insert node 
but root is not updating

Answer (score 4):

You're not advancing `root` correctly down the tree.

This:

```
if(data < (*root)->data){
    *root = (*root)->left;
}else{
    *root = (*root)->right;
}
```

should be this:

```
if(data < (*root)->data){
    root = &(*root)->left;
}else{
    root = &(*root)->right;
}
```

The purpose of the pointer-to-pointer `root` is to hold the address of a pointer that will eventually be updated to hold the pointer to the new node. As you walk down the tree, `root` should be updated to hold the address of the next potential candidate pointer. Eventually, you'll reach a pointer that is NULL, and is thus the candidate where you'll hang your new node.

And fwiw, the initial test for NULL here:

```
if(*root==NULL){
    *root = createNode(data);
    return *root;
}else{
```

is pointless, and the saving of `k` is wrong. Fixed and reduced, it should be:

```
Node *insert(Node **root,int data)
{
    Node **k = root;

    while (*root)
    {
        if (data < (*root)->data)
            root = &(*root)->left;
        else
            root = &(*root)->right;

    }
    *root = createNode(data);
    return *k;
}
```

Comment: i pass address of the node pointer in the insert function (Node **root), so in the while loop why i am not advancing the root correctly with code              *root = (*root)->left. pls explain it. what is the purpose of store              Node **k= root, why not Node *k= *root. pls clarify

Comment: @raton all `Node *k = *root;` does is save the current address of the pointer addressed by the pointer-to-pointer `root`. Think about what is stored if the initial pointer passed in (by address) was NULL. Then `k` would be NULL, a rather useless value. To be honest, this function needs no return value unless you want to communicate error state. You're already correctly passing in the caller's `root` pointer by address (pointer-to-pointer) for potential modification (which will happen on initial insert). Were it me, I'd use `int` and relay whether the insert succeeded as a status code.